# How to define/ingest a hard-coded multi-line list without using quotes

Tags: python

I have a script that operates on elements of a list
The list is hard-coded at the top of the script and is edited periodically
When adding/removing items it would be ideal not to have to "quote" each item (especially since the users that may edit it may insert entries that have quotes and need to be escaped)

i.e. right now the list is defined as:

```
blah = [
'banana1',
'banana2',
'banana3'
]
```

If I wanted to add `ban'ana4` then it would look like:

```
blah = [
'banana1',
'banana2',
'banana3',
'ban\'ana4'
]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this other than making it a multi-line text string and then splitting on linebreaks?

Comment: Might it be easier to read the list from a text file, and have the users edit the file?  There'll always be some way they can  mess up the code.

Comment: In just this specific narrow case, you can switch all elements to use double quotes `"banana"` instead of `'banana'`, as that will allow an unescaped single quote in the middle of a string "ban'ana", but for a more robust solution, I think @snakecharmerb has the right answer

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @snakecharmerb's suggestion. It's less error-prone to store string values in a text file and load them whenever you run your Python program. For example, if you store the list items in the text file "test.txt"

**test.txt**

```
banana1
banana2
banana3
ban'ana4
```

Then you can load the list of strings into your program by reading the content in the "test.txt" file:

```
FILENAME = 'test.txt'
blah = []
with open(FILENAME) as f:
    for line in f:
        # cut off newline characters \n and \r
        l = line.split('\n')[0].split('\r')[0]
        blah.append(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to avoid quoting, this is a very common idiom in python. Here is a example from repl

```
>>> '''foo
... bar'tar
... zar'''.split()
['foo', "bar'tar", 'zar']
```

Just note that line breaks are white spaces here, so `split()` just works. You will need to remove the indentation of those lines leading to another problem, this can be fixed by removing left spaces after splitting, which can be with something like the bellow

```
import re
from operator import truth

class R:
    def __rsub__(self, string):
        return list(filter(truth, re.split(r'\n\s*', string)))
R = R()


def foo():
    s = '''
    foo
    bar
    tar'zar''' - R
    print(s)

foo()
```

Just give `R` a better name :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is absolutely necessary to keep the list in the script file, I would read the data from a text file instead.  This way any quoting is handled automatically by Python, and their is no risk of typos corrupting the script.

This wouldn't work if some elements of the list are not strings, but that doesn't seem to be likely in your case.

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line.strip() for line in f]
    # do stuff with list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to include a single quote in the string or triple quotes to contain a mix of the other two:

```
blah = [
'banana1',
'banana2',
'banana3',
"ban'ana4",
"""ban'an"a5"""
]
```